# CSRF Token generation - PHP

Tags: php, forms

Ok, so I'm trying to protect my application from CRSF attacks by adding CSRF tokens to the forms... I was wondering if my implementation of this would be considered secure.

When a user authenticates (logs in) a CSRF Token is added to their session,

```
function setCSRF(){
  $randomValue = getRandom(); //Generated with dev/urandom/
  $_SESSION['CSRFtoken'] = $randomValue;
}
```

This value is then added to session forms as a hidden field, when the form is submitted the form checks the form value with the session value. If they are the same then allow the form to be processed, the form also regenerates a new unique CSRFToken so that the same one is not used by calling `setCSRF`

Would this be secure?

Comment: Ehm, you mean CSRF, right?

Comment: Yes, Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, this should work,because the attacker can not guess the random value to put it in his fake form.

**But** consider that  victim of a `csrf` attack, is a logged in user, and of course `$_SESSION['CSRFtoken']` is set for him, and if an attacker could access to a real form of a logged in user and get the token  (Hypothetical scenario), the user will be attacked easily, because the token will be the same as long as the user is logged in ( this could be a long time ).

You better generate a random string in EVERY FORM that user will submit, and set it as session and put it in a hidden input value.and check if submitted  value matches with session.and so on.

You can read these as references :

[Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

[Preventing CSRF and XSRF Attacks](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html)

[what are csrf attacks](http://www.acunetix.com/what-are-csrf-attacks/)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'm finding it difficult to find much resources on the subject specifically for PHP. Do you know of anything I can read up on? or have any suggestions as to how I can implement this correctly?

Comment: and search for 'preventing csrf attacks'

Comment: Sorry, I had to wait 10 minutes before it let me select the answer. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: look at the update again,I changed my mind, your solution is not wrong, sorry